# How can I use for loop in a shell/terminal with awk?

Tags: command-line, dpkg, text-processing, awk

The command

```
dpkg -l | awk '$2=="ufw" {sub("ubuntu[^[:alpha:]]*$", "", $3); print $3"\t"$2}'
```

outputs:

```
0.34~rc-0   ufw
```

Now instead of specifying package name like `$2=="ufw"`, I want to iterate over and get the list of all packages like this:

```
2.20.1-5.1   util-linux
1.0.2-1  zerofree
0.34~rc-0   ufw
```

**EDIT**
Made a syntax error myself. I should have directly used the same command, removing `$2=="ufw"`. The answer is `dpkg -l | awk '{sub("ubuntu[^[:alpha:]]*$", "", $3); print $3"\t"$2}'`.

Comment: Do you want any other filtering? From your description it sounds like maybe you just want [to remove `$2=="ufw"` from the command](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23826544/). That will list those columns for all lines in the output of `dpkg -l`. Is that what you want? Assuming it's not, can you explain how the output you need should differ?

Comment: I want to list all packages using for loop, I was trying something like this `for iii in dpkg -l | awk '$2==iii {sub("ubuntu[^[:alpha:]]*$", "", $3); print $3}'` that gives me error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'`

Comment: @EliahKagan Sorry Damn Stupidity I made. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tell `dpkg` to list details for specific packages:

```
$ dpkg -l util-linux ufw
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                         Version                     Architecture                Description
+++-============================================-===========================-===========================-==============================================================================================
ii  ufw                                          0.35-0ubuntu2               all                         program for managing a Netfilter firewall
ii  util-linux                                   2.27.1-6ubuntu3.1           amd64                       miscellaneous system utilities
```

Then you only need to filter out the heading.

Easier still would be to use `dpkg-query` and set the format directly:

```
$ dpkg-query -W --showformat '${Version}\t${Package}\n' util-linux ufw
0.35-0ubuntu2   ufw
2.27.1-6ubuntu3.1   util-linux
```

Then, in `awk`, you just need to remove the `ubuntu...` part as you currently do, without any filtering.

Comment: No no, You got me completely wrong, I want to list all packages using for loop

Comment: I don't want to mention package name every time

Comment: also this filtering is must for me `{sub("ubuntu[^[:alpha:]]*$", "", $3); print $3"\t"$2}'`

Comment: @Constantine if you want to list all packages, just remove `$2 == ufw` as Eliah Kagan says.

Comment: @Constantine and I assume you can read the "Then, in awk, ..." line

Comment: if I remove `$2 == ufw` it gives me syntax error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: Did you also remove the `'` before it?

Comment: I damn stupid, Sorry guys troubling you Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You found that, when you [removed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873634/how-to-use-for-loop-in-shell-terminal-using-awk?noredirect=1#comment1356120_873634) `$2=="ufw"` from the beginning of your AWK script `$2=="ufw" {sub("ubuntu[^[:alpha:]]*$", "", $3); print $3"\t"$2}`, you got the output you wanted. That is, you [reported](https://askubuntu.com/posts/873634/revisions) that this command worked:

```bash
dpkg -l | awk '{sub("ubuntu[^[:alpha:]]*$", "", $3); print $3"\t"$2}'
```

You should really use `dpkg-query` to print information about installed packages with custom formatting. **[muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/873641/22949) is the best way to do the specific task you are trying to do here.**

This answer explains why it was that `$2=="ufw"` prevented `awk` from processing each line of input as you intended.

---

As [the GNU Awk User's Guide says](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getting-Started.html#Getting-Started), an AWK script consists of rules that specify a pattern and, in curly `{` `}` braces, the action that should be taken when that pattern is matched.

```
pattern { action }
```

When the pattern is omitted, the action is carried out for every line of input. In practice, that is the most common way to write an AWK rule.

```
{ action }
```

That is also what you intended: you wanted to operate on and produce a line of output for each line of input.

```
{sub("ubuntu[^[:alpha:]]*$", "", $3); print $3"\t"$2}
```

But you had a pattern specified as well:

```
$2=="ufw" {sub("ubuntu[^[:alpha:]]*$", "", $3); print $3"\t"$2}
```

This caused your action to be applied only to those lines whose second field (`$2`) was equal (`==`) to `ufw` (`"ufw"`). But there is only one package whose name is exactly `ufw`, and thus only one line about it in the output of `dpkg -l`.

Removing the pattern caused the action to be done for all lines of input, and not just the single line about the `ufw` package.